# Android: Loading Video View Then Swapping to Application After Initialization is Complete

Tags: android, video, view, loading

Update:
I ended up separating out the video player into a separate activity and layout. I then started this activity using the code below.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        startActivityForResult(new Intent(MainActivity.this, VideoActivity.class), VIDEO_PID); //load video
//etc.
}
```

When the app is loaded, I call this function to kill the Video Activity and bring the main activity to the front:

```
public void doneLoading() {
    finishActivity(VIDEO_PID);
}
```

I don't know if this is the best way, but it worked.

=======================

What's the easiest way of showing a centered VideoView and then switching to a WebView after the application is fully loaded? I verified that both these views work when included individually in the app. I just want to only show the VideoView when loading, then hide it until the application is closed.

I was looking into ViewPager and ViewFlipper, but I haven't gotten anything working yet. I was going to avoid including them in separate activities. PageViewer seemed to manage the views (meaning allow them to run and init themselves), but not actually display them (all I saw was a black screen). I'm probably missing something.

Would it be easier to start the loading video then start off another activity that initializes the webview, which requests focus and sends a message for the loading video activity to quit after initialization is finished?

My layout is below to give an idea of what I'm using.
Thanks.

P.S. I'm avoiding the use of Fragments for Gingerbread support.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/videoview_component"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
        <WebView  
            android:id="@+id/webview_component"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="0dip"
        />
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How do you define "the application is fully loaded?"

Comment: Also, you do know about the compatability packages which add Fragment support to 1.6+ right? (http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html)

Comment: "Fully loaded" is determined by a javascript callback being executed within the webview. The activity listens for this callback. I didn't know that Fragment was part of the support library. I was actually using the library already for the NotificationCompat class.